# MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED flag set

Tags: c++, file

So the msdn page for MoveFileEx states that for MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED:

If the file is to be moved to a different volume, the function simulates the move by using the CopyFile and DeleteFile functions.
If the file is successfully copied to a different volume and the original file is unable to be deleted, the function succeeds leaving the source file intact.

Now my question is firstly, when it says volume i assume that just means a different location on your hdd?
Following that assumption, If i make a file that is read only. Then i call MoveFileEx with the MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED flag set, should it not just move the file using CopyFile. then when it tries to delete the file it should fail, because DeleteFile cannot delete read only files.

Im doing the above except that the file is deleting from the old location. My only thought was that volume means something different to what i say above.

Answer (score 1):

`Volume` means a different drive (partition) on your system, such as from `C:` to `D:`, or from your local drive to a remote drive (or vice versa).

If you're copying to the same volume (for instance, from `C:\Test\` to `C:\TestTwo\`, they're on the same volume.

I don't see anything in the docs that say `If the file is read-only and therefore unable to be deleted`. I see `If the file is unable to be deleted`, which probably means `If the file is in use or you don't have proper rights in the source  location to delete it`. After all, you're asking to move the file by calling `MoveFileEx`.

If you don't want the file deleted, don't call `MoveFile` or `MoveFileEx`; use `CopyFile` instead, which is what you apparently want to do.

Comment: Ive tried this now. I create a file at C:\temp. Then i use MoveFileEx to move it somewhere on my O: drive. But it is still deleting off my C: when i move it even though it is a read only file.

Comment: Im testing a FSD for external hardware and im testing to make sure things happen on this like they would occur on Windows Explorer. The doc says it uses CopyFile and DeleteFile. If you try to use DeleteFile on a read only file it fails. Thats my issue.

Comment: So use `CopyFile` and `DeleteFile`. `MoveFile` implies (by it's very name) that you want to **move** the file. If you pick up a stack of papers from one desk and **move** them to a different one, they don't stay on the first desk. If you make a copy of the papers and put the copy on desk #2, you have a stack of papers on both desks. :-)

Comment: I have to test the MoveFileEx function through the FSD though to ensure it can be used with no problems

Comment: `MoveFile` **can** apparently be used with no problems, since you're complaining that it actually **moves** the file. ??? You seem to be operating under the assumption that Explorer uses `MoveFileEx`; do you know for a fact it does?

Comment: no, but i need to test everything. A developer might create code that will use MoveFileEx for use passing files thorugh the FSD. So i need to test that it works.

Comment: And im not complaining that it moves the file. It is meant to move the file. What i dont undestand is how it deletes the file if it is using DeleteFile and that cannot delete a read only file

Comment: I give up. :-) Apparently I'm not understanding your question properly.

Comment: Well, it's easy to understand, if you know that FSD means: file system driver. So the OP tries to figure out if a file system supported by that driver behaves exactly like any other Windows file system.

Comment: @Matthias: Yes, I'm fully aware what FSD means. I've probably been writing code since before you were in diapers. :-) Thanks for chiming in on a nearly 11 year old question to tell me something I already know, though.